Formal test for externally studentized residuals
Under the typical assumptions of the linear model, externally studentized residuals are defined as
\begin{align}
t_i = \dfrac{e_i}{s_{-i}\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}}
\end{align}
which has a $t_{n-p-1}$ distribution. The question is: why shouldn't I use this to formally (given $\alpha$) test that the observation with the greatest $t_i$ is an outlier? What changes if I deterministically choose such observation, instead of randomly choosing one?

This is the standard way of performing an outlier test.  Examples of tests of this kind include Grubbs test (see e.g., Grubbs 1969).  The basic idea of the test is to examine the residual value with the largest magnitude (absolute value) and compare this value to the null distribution of the largest residual.$^\dagger$  If we reject the null hypothesis then we conclude that there is evidence of at least one "outlier" in the data (i.e., an observation that does not come from the stipulated distribution).  One can then iteratively repeat the test on the next largest observation, etc., to determine if there is evidence of more than one outlier.
In the event that you find evidence of one or more outliers in your data, this typically means that the stipulated error distribution does not have sufficiently "fat tails" to adequately represent the true deviation of values from their mean.  In the case of a Gaussian regression model, failure of the Grubbs test generally means that the true distribution of the error terms has fatter tails than a normal distribution (e.g., a leptokurtic distribution).  An appropriate solution would then be to switch to an error distribution with fatter tails (e.g., T distribution or generalised error distribution).

$^\dagger$ The fact that you are choosing the residual with the highest magnitude just means that you have to compare it to the null distribution of the highest magnitude residual out of a set of $n$ residuals.  You would typically do this by using simulation methods to determine the null distribution conditional on your explanatory variables.

If you have chosen the $i$th observation (say, "Mary") beforehand of being of special interest, then you can compare $t_i$ to the $t$-distribution. But this implies that your special interest is in whether "Mary" could be an outlier or not. This is called the "labelled" outlier test. If you want to test whether there exist any outliers in the data, you would use the maximum of the $t_i$s. But this is not a $t$-distribution. Instead it is the distribution of the maximum of $n$ correlated externally studentized residuals, which is hard to tackle. There is a vast literature on this topic and a lot of approximations to this distribution.
